# Using ADO for ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

One of my project requirements is to make a DLL or a helper that will contain all my interaction with the DB and to use ADO instead of EF.

Here is what i have so far:

```
namespace repository
{
public class access
{
    public string connectionString { get; set; }

    public access()
    {
        connectionString = "Data Source=KISHGAL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=carl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123456ca;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
    }



    public DataSet getData()
    {

        string query = "select * from department";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);

        DataSet temp = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(temp, "test");

        return temp;

    }


}
}
```

I couldn't find any good examples and usage of DataSet(my client wants me to use DataSet). So i wanna ask if i am on the right track?

I invoke everything from my controller by doing something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult test()
{
    List<departments> dep = new List<departments>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in cont.getData().Tables["test"].Rows)
    {
        dep.Add(new departments()
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
            dname = Convert.ToString(dr["dname"])
        });
    }
    return View(dep);
}
```

So far, i am able to fetch rows and display them from my view but i would like to know how to optimize my code or if there is anything that i missed?

Comment: Returning dataset from DAL is a bad idea.

Comment: What is the point of returning a `DataSet` - you the need to convert it to `IEnumerable<T>` to use it anyway. Just read the data into you model.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri can you elaborate more on that? what should i alter on my helper?

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you mean that i should convert it to IEnumerable already before i return it?

Comment: I meant why is you service not returning `IEnumerable<departments>` (or `List<departments>`) instead of `DataSet` since that's what you seem to need.

Comment: YOu have only one table to fetch data only ID and Name, See there are many ways to make things better but based on scenario, Do not start applying something generic. Everyone has their own experience based on their situation. You may bind data directly to your control without iterating for now. Which at least make your application make it little faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better to separate out your query a little bit; You can have your  methods for Create, Update, Delete and Insert as the methods of your class . below code T is a generic type you can use it to pass in a list of type T to the method. Any type basically , your query statements should be separated - so that you can have an encapsulated dll - and the DB tables, do not matter the access of them is the same - the query is passed in to the dll method and you can use that base library for any ER model. There are other ways to do this as well DAL is what this functionality is referred as.

```
public DataSet SelectAll(string table)
{//.. code to select all}
public DataSet Select(string query)
{//.. code to select all}

public int Insert<T>(List<T> values)
{//.. code to select all}

public int Update<T>(List<T> values)
{//.. code to select all}
```

Comment: Ooo i see, interesting answer let me try it out.

Comment: @Carlos Miguel Colanta - I wrote it quickly so where you see code to select all in each one - it is really code to select or update or run query. Yes as others say returning dataset is a lot of overhead not too mention depending on how it comes (like for example via WCF) could pose a security risk you can public void List<T> Select<T>(query){//...code}

Comment: ahhh so i should just return them as List directly?

Comment: Yes because generally that is what you want anyway - a list of items. if you want or need something else for example column names returning a datatable will give you that. There are special situations for different things. also you will need to make sure you reference : using System.Collections.Generic when using generics the <T>.
The more generic you keep your classes the easier it can be to add functionalities to code with out having to write a whole lot of specific functionality. Keep your classes simple, and concise. Will make things easier for you.

Comment: The other thing is your code to get data becomes this easy 2 lines and faster - no iteration.
public ActionResult test()
{
    List<departments> dep = MyDAL.SelectAll<departments>("table");
    return View(dep);
}

Comment: My classes or DTO are stored in the same project as my asp mvc. Should i move them to the same project as my DAL? i am having a hard time referencing them since my DAL doesn't know the classes from my main project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97699/discussion-between-stixo-and-carlos-miguel-colanta).